# Remove a ZFS attribute instead of setting its value to default?

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

I added a ZFS property which was not included by default. Instead of setting it back to true (default value), is there a way to "remove" the attribute I created?

```
root@library:~# zfs get all | grep false
library/secure   com.sun:auto-snapshot       true    local
```

Comment: Is`zfs inherit` what you're looking for?

Comment: It doesn't remove the property from the root. [edited] Nevermind yes it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
root@library:~# zfs get all | grep "com.sun:auto-snapshot "
library/secure      com.sun:auto-snapshot       false    local com.sun:auto-snapshot       false                            local

root@library:~# zfs inherit com.sun:auto-snapshot library/secure
root@library:~# zfs get all | grep "com.sun:auto-snapshot "
root@library:~#
```